# Is it possible to have particles update at half the framerate?

Tags: animation, particles

I'm trying to make an animated fire that plays at a 12fps but still have the camera move at 24fps. For the fire itself, i used the stepped interpolation modifier and that worked fine, but now I'm trying to do the same with the particles emitting from the fire. I've been searching for hours but haven't found anything.[image: fire]